# Using TreeItemLabel for TreeItem in VSCode Extension

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm building a Tree View VSCode extension and would like to highlight a portion of my tree item's labels in certain situations. It seems like a [TreeItemLabel](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TreeItemLabel) supports this functionality via the `highlights` property.

The [API docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TreeItem) specify that one of the constructor signatures for `TreeItem` accepts a `TreeItemLabel` as the first argument. The [docs for TreeItemLabel](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#TreeItemLabel) only show two properties for this object (`hightlights?` and `label`) without any constructor. I'm fairly new to the JS/TS world, and am not sure of how to "pass in" a `TreeItemLabel` to the constructor of a `TreeItem`.

I can't seem to import `TreeItemLabel` from anywhere in the `vscode` namespace, which eliminates the possibility of using a constructor.

I found a [sample test](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/0e9c32e1bbd23e931a28d010bc2c8fb9974ea475/tree-view-sample/src/testView.ts#L78) that seems to manually construct a `TreeItem` with a `highlights` property by explicitly defining an object with those properties, but I'm not sure how to translate this to my use case.

In my case, I have a class that extends `TreeItem` and passes some values to `super()` to make the TreeItem:

```
export class Org extends vscode.TreeItem {
    public readonly contextValue = 'org';

    constructor(
        public readonly name: string,
        public readonly devName: string,
        public readonly tooltip: string, 
        public readonly collapsibleState: vscode.TreeItemCollapsibleState
    ) {
        super(name, collapsibleState);
    }

    iconPath = vscode.ThemeIcon.File;
}
```

How do I change my call to `super()` such that I can utilize a `TreeItemLabel`?
Thanks in advance!

Edit #1:

When I attempt to define the properties I want as the first argument in my call to `super()` like so:

```
constructor(
        // The name displayed in the tree view
        public readonly name: string,
        // The name of the org (without anything extra added)
        public readonly devName: string,
        public readonly tooltip: string, 
        public readonly collapsibleState: vscode.TreeItemCollapsibleState
    ) {
        super({label:name, highlights:[0,2]}, collapsibleState);
    }
```

I get the following:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(label: string, collapsibleState?: TreeItemCollapsibleState | undefined): TreeItem', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ label: string; highlights: number[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(resourceUri: Uri, collapsibleState?: TreeItemCollapsibleState | undefined): TreeItem', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ label: string; highlights: number[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Uri'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'label' does not exist in type 'Uri'.ts(2769)
```

Comment: looks like the type definition of the class constructor differs from the type definition used by intellisense, What does intellisense shows you when you construct a `TreeItem` with `new TreeItem(`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define an object with the properties you need. You might need to change the numbers based on the `name` string.

```js
export class Org extends vscode.TreeItem {
    public readonly contextValue = 'org';

    constructor(
        public readonly name: string,
        public readonly devName: string,
        public readonly tooltip: string, 
        public readonly collapsibleState: vscode.TreeItemCollapsibleState
    ) {
        super({label:name, highlights:[[0,5],[9,12]]}, collapsibleState);
    }

    iconPath = vscode.ThemeIcon.File;
}
```

Comment: @Brand0R I tried it in a JavaScript Extension and it worked but I had to change the `highlights` argument (it is an array of tuples)